# Upgrading from MVC 2 to MVC 4

Tags: asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-2, asp.net-mvc-4

I wanted to upgrade my project to ASP .NET MVC 4.  Currently, I have 2 projects in my solution.  One's the MVC 2 project as the UI layer and the other one for my business logic.  In order to upgrade to MVC 4, I was thinking of adding a new MVC 4 project to my solution, and copy over everything from my MVC 2 project, and just change the syntax in my views to use the razor syntax.

Question is, since I'll be having two UI projects in my solution at the same time (MVC 2 and MVC 4), when I run the solution, will I have the option to run either and ignore the other one?

Is this a good way to upgrade?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You would just right-click the one you want to run and choose the "Set as startup project" option.  I've done this many times where I have multiple web applications in a single solution.

Answer (score 3):

You could just run the [mvc3 updater](http://aspnet.codeplex.com/releases/view/59008) then follow the standard documentation to migrate mvc3 -> 4.

This is probably a better approach if you don't have time to convert all of the views to razor (and there's really no need to do this straight away).